# Subtracting internal Strings within external String in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm wondering if there is any way to subtract Strings that are contained within another String in Java based on the selection of a user.

This is the code that I have:

```
removeIng = pH1 + pH2 + pH3;  
System.out.print("Enter number corresponding to element you want to remove");  
System.out.printf("%s",removeIng);  
remove = in.nextInt();  
switch(remove)  
{  
case 1:  
    removeIng = pH2 + pH3;  
case 2:  
    removeIng = pH1 + pH3;  
case 3:  
    removeIng = pH1 + pH2;  
}
```

I need the code to be dynamic so that the user could possibly remove all the elements if they want. I have an outside loop already created to allow for that possibility. But I'm at a loss as to how to have "removeIng" subtract the user selected element. I can figure out the other part. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've found ways to subtract strings that are declared as "blah blah" but nothing like this. Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: You do realize String is immutable in Java, yes? You can create a new String, but never change the contents of one.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you. I guess I'll need to create the new string.

Comment: @Brian based on comments below he did not know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample code, it might be easier to keep track of which bits of the string the user doesn't want, and generate `removeIng` based on that. Here's some pseudocode. I sacrificed optimization in favor of clarity:

```
String[] components;
// what used to be called pH1 is accessed by components[0];
boolean[] deletedPieces;
// initially set to all false
// contains true for segments that the user wants to delete, false otherwise

your outer loop here {
    // ask the user which piece to delete here
    remove = in.nextInt() - 1; // - 1 to account for array indices starting at 0

    deletedPieces[remove] = true;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < total number of possible pieces; i++) {
        if(deletedPieces[i])
            // user wanted this piece deleted; do nothing
        else
            sb.append(components[i]);
    }

    removeIng = sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Lord Torgamus, I'm actually new to arrays. We're learning that in class this next week. The only thing I know so far about arrays is that to create an array of integers I would use int[]. I'm looking on Oracle's site about ArrayLists and I don't quite understand how to initialize the arraylist... "public static ArrayList"? Thanks for your help, by the way. I think the code above will work if I can figure this one thing out.

Comment: @Michael, since it's only pseudocode anyways, I modified it to use arrays instead of ArrayLists. Is it more clear this way?

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. One more question, if you don't mind. In the arrays that I'm creating for "String" where do I then declare pH1 and pH2, etc.? Or do I even need to? I understand how the components[0] works, so that's not an issue.

Comment: @Michael, you don't need pH1 anymore. Wherever you used pH1 in the past, just use components[0]; wherever you used pH2, use components[1], etc.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you. Is the String[] that's being referred to in your code a new string or is it the removeIng string? I guess I'm not quite sure how to initialize the string... "public static String []"? or public static String remove []? Sorry, I probably sound very inept... which I probably am... :)

Comment: @Michael if you've not gotten around to arrays yet and you're in school then I say you're on track. I will add one more piece of assigned reading on top of the classwork tho. Code Complete 2. Try to get through the first couple hundred pages, even if it doesn't make 100% sense. If you can do the whole book before the end of the semester, awesome, but overkill. Well worth having on your bookshelf dogeared.

Comment: String[] means an array of Strings. So in your current code you probably say `String pH1 = "foo"; String pH2 = "bar";` somewhere. Now, you write `components[0] = "foo"; components[1] = "bar";` instead. It's pretty much exactly like an array of ints, except they're Strings instead of ints.

Comment: You're awesome Lord Torgamus. Thank you for your help and answer to my basic questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try `String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)). There is also [a version of this method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that uses regular expressions, if you need a more powerful replacement syntax.

Comment: This won't work if parts of the strings overlap with each other, for example pH1 is a, pH2 is ab and pH3 is abc and the user removes 1.

Comment: Would it be easier then to change the nested strings' names?

Comment: sk, is it then possible to add this piece of code in place of "removeIng = pH2 + pH3" in the example above:

Comment: sorry, hit enter too soon...    "replace = String.replace(pH1," ")" to insert nothing inplace of "pH1"

Comment: @Michael, _is_ there any possibility that one of your strings is a subset of any of your other strings? Or even a concatenation of some of your other strings?